# Instagram Private API to change your bio

Tags: python

Fairly new to python but trying to learn.

Im attempting to change my instagram bio using the follow code.

```
    from instagram_private_api import Client, ClientCompatPatch

user_name = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

api = Client(user_name, password)
api.edit_profile('Test', 'Testing', 'test', 'test@gmail.com', '5555555555', 1)
```

According to the documentation the syntax of the edit_profile is this.

edit_profile(first_name, biography, external_url, email, phone_number, gender)

However when I run my code I get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "insta.py", line 7, in                                                                                       api.edit_profile('Test', 'Testing', 'test', 'test@gmail.com', '5555555555', 1)                                           File "C:\Users\Del\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\instagram_private_api\endpoints\accounts.py", line 111, in edit_profile                            res = self._call_api('accounts/edit_profile/', params=params)                                                         File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\instagram_private_api\client.py", line 527, in _call_api                                           ErrorHandler.process(e, error_response)                                                                               File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\instagram_private_api\errors.py", line 122, in process                                             if re.search(p, error_message_type):                                                                                  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\re.py", line 185, in search                                                                                                              return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)                                                                      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Im not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone point me in the right direction. I am providing the correct strings right?

Comment: i would not be able to format your traceback BC it has a lot of spaces in it. but you need to make the traceback readable and in a codeblock

Answer (score 0):

Package you are trying to import is compatible upto python 3.5 only
Try to run it on python 2

Comment: Tried using python 2.7 and getting the same output.

Comment: @magificul you can try this:-  `api.edit_profile('', 'Python Developer', 'https://github.com/itsvinitjain/itsvinitjain', 'test@gmail.com', '+916734455667', 1)`